# How can I get rid of this error when apt update and instal git

Tags: ubuntu, apt, git

I'm new in Linux and i am using Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS. I am tring to install git with following steps in [this](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-git-on-ubuntu-18-04/) site. When I run `sudo apt update` or `sudo apt-get update` command that returns this errors:

**sudo apt update**

```
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                  
Err:3 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                                         
  Temporary failure resolving 'tr.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                                 
  Temporary failure resolving 'tr.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'tr.archive.ubuntu.com'
Fetched 109 kB in 36s (3.074 B/s)       
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'tr.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'tr.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'tr.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have also tried `sudo apt-get update`
I have tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error) solution in https://askubuntu.com/ but changing DNS is not solved my `Temporary failure resolving 'tr.archive.ubuntu.com'`and according to second part of this solution I shall remove `deb http:/archive.canonical.com/ natty backports` line from my `source.list` but i already don't have this.

**My sources.list**

[image: sources.list]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The servers seem to be down as pinging fails:

```
 ping tr.archive.ubuntu.com
```

The simplest circumvention would be to directly use `archive.ubuntu.com`, i.e. removing the `tr.` prefix.

Ubuntu archives usually have a local mirror to ease the load on the main servers and reduce traffic around the globe for speed reasons. Why the `tr.`-mirrors are down and if that is permanent cannot be said. Usually they should work.